# How can I get specific field value with array nested filter in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

After I filtered nested array values then I added "$project" query for selecting specific fields.

I want to get "new_yn" field values outside of the nested array but I only got id and nested array values.

How can I fix my Query? Would you give me some guides?
(MongoDB version is 5.0.6 Community)

**[Query]**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "new_yn": "Y",
      "port_info": {
        $elemMatch: {
          "port_code": "http_https"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      port_info: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$port_info",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$item.port_code",
              "http_https"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "new_yn": 1,
      "port_info.ip_port": 1
    }
  }
])
```

**[Mongo Playground]**

https://mongoplayground.net/p/OXOaz8ct4KA

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ohSkR77mVAT

Comment: Wow. Thank you for your help again! @nimrodserok I'm newbie in MongoDB. I think "$set" is only used in insert or update queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you haven't included it in the first `$project` stage.

Just add `new_yn:1` to the first project stage and it will work.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "new_yn": "Y",
      "port_info": {
        $elemMatch: {
          "port_code": "http_https"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      new_yn: 1,
      port_info: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$port_info",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$item.port_code",
              "http_https"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "new_yn": 1,
      "port_info.ip_port": 1
    }
  }
])
```

As [suggested by Bethlee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72388151/how-can-i-get-specific-field-value-with-array-nested-filter-in-mongodb/72388371#comment127880336_72388151), you can use [`$set`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-set) as well, but it will bring all other  fields from that document, which I believe you dont want.

Comment: Thank you for helping me and attaching detail description about the query.